# Example of weak convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, examples-counterexamples, weak-convergence

I'd like to understand better the concept of weak convergence.

I know that a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ converges weakly to $\mu$ if $\int{f d\mu_n}$ converges to $\int{f d\mu}$ for each $f$ which is continuous and bounded.

Could you please give me an example of a sequence of probability measures $\mu_n$ that converges weakly to $\mu$ and find a function $f$ such that $\int{f d\mu_n}$ does not converge to $\int{f d\mu}$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $P(X_n=1/n)=1$, let $P(X=0)=1$.  The probability distribution of $X_n$ is $\mu_n=\delta_{1/n}$,  the point-mass measure concentrated at $1/n$, that of $X$ is the point mass at $0$, namely $\mu=\delta_0$.

We can check that $\mu_n$ converges to $\mu$ weakly: since $\int f d\mu_n = f(1/n)$ and $\int f d\mu=f(0)$, for continuous and bounded $f$ the desired limit holds: $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(1/n)=f(0)$.

But for $f=\chi_{\{0\}}$, say, the indicator function of the singleton set $\{0\}$, we have $\int f d\mu_n = 0$ and $\int f d\mu = 1$, so the desired limit does not hold.  This $f$ is bounded but not continuous.

Comment: Is there a nice way to prove $\int f d\mu_n = f(1/n)$?  It seems obvious, of course, but I'm not sure how to prove it without a long-winded argument. I am tempted to go through all the steps of constructing the Lebesgue integral.  But this seems unnecessarily complicated. The construction of Lebesgue integral makes it easy to handle integrals are simple due to constraints on $f$ (e.g., if $f$ is a simple function).  However, here we have an integral which is simple due to a constraint on $\mu$.    Context: I've studied Ash's probability and measure theory through Sec 2.8 (weak convergence).

Comment: @ashman I don't have Ash's book, so cannot tell what would constitute a "proof" starting from what's stated in it through sec. 2.8.  How would you define the point-mass measure $\delta_a$, for instance? One might appeal to the Riesz-Markov theorem to note that since the map $f\mapsto f(a)$ is  continuous and bounded on $C[0,1]$  there exists a Borel measure $\mu$ such that $\int_0^1 f(x)\mu(dx)=f(a)$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$, and $\delta_a$ simply  our notation for that measure. Does this make sense with the way Ash's book develops the subject?

Answer (score 1):

Take on $[0,1]$ the measures $\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\delta_{k/n}$.
They converge weakly to the Lebesgue measure $\mu=\lambda^1$ restricted to $[0,1]\,$, because the Riemann sum $\mu_n(f)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n f(\frac{k}{n})$ converges to its integral $\mu(f)=\int_{[0,1]}f(x)\,dx$ for every bounded continuous function $f$.

Let's break the continuous condition, but be sure not to take a Lipschitz function (see Portmanteau theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures)

Let $f$ be the Dirichlet function $f=\chi_{\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}$.
You have $1=\mu_n(f)\neq\mu(f)=0\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$